# IBM Urbancode Deploy - Supply values to parameters at runtime using properties

Tags: properties, ucd

I have created a process in IBM UCD to deploy a .Net application. 
My Scenario is that i should be able to provide different application name at run time each time i run the process. How can we do this using property in IBM UCD.

I have tried enabling "Prompt on use" option and also created component property and mapped it to the parameter say ${p:component/application.name} but doesn't seem to work. May be i missing out some sequence of steps.

It would be great if i get detailed steps to making this working.

Answer (score 1):

I take it that you are on version 4.x (uDeploy)?

I would steer clear of the prompt on use approach, that feature was removed in 6.x. While there is a migration in place, its simpler to just avoid it.

Using a property on the component process itself is the way to go. So go to your process configuration, and go to the properties / configuration tab. Create a property there. You'll be prompted for a value whenever you run an application process that uses this component process.

If the property is named "iis.app.name" you would reference it with just ${p:iss.app.name}.

**Don't use the property "application.name".** That is an automatically created property that gets the name of the UCD Application that you are deploying. If you ever can't find out the right way to reference a property, look at your executed process (at component / application levels). The normal view that lists out all the steps that were run and how long they took is sitting on a tab called "Log". Right next to it is "Properties" tab. Click that and you'll see what properties were available to the process.

Also, you'll have better luck getting fast answers about UC Deploy using their own forum: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/?community=urbancode

Comment: Let me explain the steps which i followed to create a component process property and referencing it to the parameter of the component process.
1. Under component process, i created a component process property with name "iss.app.name" with label "Application name".
2. Then i went back to the component process step and changed the value of Application Name as ${p:iss.app.name}
3. On running the application process, it prompted me for Application Name. I provided a value "ABC"

But it's throwing "undefined" error on that particular step.

Comment: Also to add on, i am using version 6.0.1.0.455295 of IBM UCD.

Comment: Odd. I'd go into the component process log and hit the properties tab to see if the property is showing up there in any way.

Answer (score -1):

Did you tried using process plugin for updating the property file ?

Application >> Process >> Select Process >> Process Editor -- From left panel you can Utility plugins , try with update property option.